# Computing $\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\frac{z}{\ln\left(z!\right)}^{n}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, factorial, closed-form, gamma-function

I am trying to compute
$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left(\frac{z}{\ln\left(z!\right)}\right)^{n}$$
The problem arises when dealing with inversion formulae. My question is, can this expression be evaluated in closed form?

My attempts:

I wrote $\dfrac{1}{\ln(z!)}$ as $\dfrac{1}{1+\ln(\frac{z!}{e})}$ and tried using the binomial theorem. After some manipulations we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(-n-i\right)\right)\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}x^{n}\ln\left(\frac{x!}{e}\right)^{k}$$

But to me this did not seem to be any closer to a solution. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: $z!$ is not a function defined on all real $z.$ Maybe you mean $\Gamma(z+1)?$

Comment: What about $\ln(x)$ as a limit? You are solving $\ln(z!)+a z=b$?

Comment: I would start by asking why you want to find this particular derivative, because the context in which it appears could be helpful in knowing how to tackle it (or whether there's a reason to tackle it at all).